# Using assertions in NUnit to confirm that an element is present on a webpage

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, web-testing

So i'm using `NUnit` and `Selenium` to test out a series of action on a website to see if the results are consistent and match our predictions. The language in using is `C#`.

```
[Test]
    public void SearchInvoiceDate()
    {
        //Clicks on dropdown menu, chooses Invoice Date and searches a date
        new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("SearchSelect"))).SelectByText("Invoice Date");
        new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("YearsList"))).SelectByText("2014");

        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("InvoiceTable_processing")).GetCssValue("display") == "none");

        new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("MonthsList"))).SelectByText("Feb");

        Assert.That();
    }
```

The test has a setup that logs into a website, clicks a dropdown option, types into a seachbar, and then loads a certain web-page.

My main goal is to run the test and see if an href link is present in a generated table

Thanks in advance for the help, i'm still new to web testing and to asking questions on stack overflow so structured criticism is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates that your test assembly has a reference to both the nunit framework and the Microsoft (MSTest) unit test framework. If you are using NUnit, drop the Microsoft reference. If you are using MSTest, drop the NUnit reference.